# dual boot ubuntu and windows 7.failed to boot into windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows, restart

I have installed windows 7 firstly and then ubuntu quantal quetzal o.s ..when i enter into grub showing options windows 7 and ubuntu,when i click windows 7.system is restarting and grub is again displayed.ubuntu is noramally working.I had tried to update grub to grub2.And i had done all possible way to update grub.But im facing that problem again.system is restarting when i click the option windows 7.what to doo??

Comment: There should be an error message given. Please post it.

Answer (score 0):

Was your windows 7 system working normaly last time?

If yes, then
try to re-install grub2 into your main HDD (for example /dev/sda)

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

You may wanna check this out https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing